# FileCopy Loop not processing more than 1st file

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I am using a background worker to run a FileCopy loop. All the paths are correct but when the loop runs, only the first file in the first folder to be copied is processed. Can anyone see where I am going wrong? I can see that since the `Console.WriteLine("Next File about to start")` is not firing. I think the issue is in the `Filestream` loop but I cannot see the issue. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Dim SourceDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(line)
                Dim DestDir As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo(FullDestPath)
                Dim ChildFile As FileInfo

            'Loop through each file in the SourceDir
            For Each ChildFile In SourceDir.GetFiles()

                Console.WriteLine(ChildFile.FullName)

                'Display file being copied
                SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblStatus, "Copying: " & line & "\" & ChildFile.Name & "")

                'Do the copy
                ChildFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, ChildFile.Name), True)

                deststring = DestDir.ToString & "\" & ChildFile.Name
                Dim sourcedirstring As String
                sourcedirstring = SourceDir.ToString & "\" & ChildFile.Name

                'Open Stream
                Dim CopyStream As New FileStream(sourcedirstring, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                Dim NewStream As New FileStream(deststring, FileMode.Append)
                Dim Buffer(100000) As Byte
                Dim BytesRead As Integer

                'Try loop for each file
                Try
                    Do
                        Timer6.Start()
                        BytesRead = CopyStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
                        NewStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead)


                        percentageTotal = ((NewStream.Length + filetotalsofarcopied) / Overallsize.ToString * 100)
                        percentageTotal = Decimal.Round((percentageTotal), 2)
                        If percentageTotal > 100 Then
                            percentageTotal = 0
                        End If

                        SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblTotalProgress, "" & percentageTotal & "%")

                        Dim time As Long = Label22.Text

                        'Calculate copy speed
                        Dim kbps As Double = (NewStream.Length + filetotalsofarcopied) / (time * 1024)
                        If kbps < 1024 Then
                            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblCopy, String.Format("Copy Speed: {0:0.00} KB/s", kbps))
                        Else
                            SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblCopy, String.Format("Copy Speed: {0:0.00} MB/s", kbps / 1024))
                        End If

                    Loop Until BytesRead = 0 And percentageTotal = 100

                Catch ex As Exception
                Finally
                    CopyStream.Dispose()
                    NewStream.Dispose()
                End Try

                'File counter
                int3 = int3 + 1

                'Calculate data being moved for eta to completion
                Dim filetotalbytes As Double = ChildFile.Length
                filetotalsofarcopied = filetotalbytes + filetotalsofarcopied

                Console.WriteLine(filetotalsofarcopied)

                'Check for pending cancel
                If BackgroundWorker1.CancellationPending = True Then
                    BackgroundWorker1.CancelAsync()
                    Exit Sub
                End If

                Console.WriteLine("Next File about to start")
            Next

            'Loop through Sub directories of SourceDir
            Dim SubDir As DirectoryInfo
                For Each SubDir In SourceDir.GetDirectories()
                    CopyDirectory(SubDir.FullName, Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, SubDir.Name), Overwrite)
                Next

        Loop Until r.EndOfStream

    End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: Try placing a breakpoint at the loop until line and inspecting the stop condition. The percentageTotal logic seems iffy, can't verify it without the full code of overallsize etc.

Comment: I'm guessing that somewhere you're getting an exception. Comment out all the exception handling code. It's a very bad idea to have an empty `Catch` block as it effectively makes your program ignore errors. `Try..Catch` code is only to handle unexpected errors that you haven't allowed for in your code, and should ALWAYS include some sort of code to handle the errors in the `Catch` block